# How to get the data to Feature Space Y from Input Space I

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am trying to implement a Support Vector Machine to understand in and out of it but I am stuck on how to implement it.
Everywhere it is explained how to get a hyper-plane such that we are able to separate different classes. My question is **how to get the data to Feature Space *Y* from Input Space *I*.**

Like for example consider below data:

```
date                 userId      pc        activity

01/04/2010 07:12:31  RES0962     PC-3736   Connect
01/04/2010 07:35:40  RES0962     PC-2588   Disconnect 
01/04/2010 08:02:14  ZKH0388     PC-1021   Connect
01/04/2010 08:20:17  ZKH0388     PC-3736   Disconnect
```

Q) Assuming we are trying to build a User behavior model. We can extract features of each user and use it to train but in terms of code how its working? I have no idea about that. If someone could explain that it would be of great help.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What do [feature space] `Y` and [input space] `I` mean? What do you mean by "User behaviour model"? What's your target and what're your features?

Comment: So by input space I mean input data.
Feature space is the feature extracted from the input data.
suppose a user visits couple of websites everyday but one day he visits a new website which he has never visited before I should be able to catch that deviation from behavior that is what I meant by User behavior model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping to feature space requires you to have a weight for each of the distinct feature that determine the classes of your input. Getting the weight is a function of clearly understood the theoretical basis of your project e.g Your financial worth is determined by Money in bank and Investment. The weight of money in bank might be 2; while for investment mightt be 5. therefore, somebody with more investment and less money will likely be with more networths.

Now, the two features money in bank and investment will now be treated as a cordinate x and y respectively as you wished for each inputed data(of course with two features). Imagine you plot the graph after knowing each data (x, y) cordinate based on your weight. Then, getting the hyperplane will be the next challenge. I hope this help. Good luck